# Where can I find resources on how to animate/morph simple masses for architects?

Tags: animation

I enjoy explanations to Blender modelling on youtube, but as an Architect i want to explain concept like the 'big companies'with the big budgets...

I want to be able to communicate concepts through video and simple 'morphing' animations as masses change in shape. Blender seems to be the perfect tool.

Please could I ask you to help me find the right resources to be able to achieve animations like these from HOK, BIG & Diller Scofidio + Renfro - lots of firms are doing this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbPMor02ago

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahbXjHFThvA

https://vimeo.com/173956112

I would really appreciate assistance if at all possible.
If there are already tutorials on youtube, perhaps someone could point me to them.